# Requirement for a high-speed (10 Mbit/s) PCI-bus synchronous serial port

Tags: serial

What high-speed PCI-bus SSP can be recommened, capable of 10 Mbit/s supplied with suitable drivers to interface to a [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) application?

- Data is sent via [RS-422](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-422) type drivers with differential twisted screened pairs terminated at both ends.
- Data is accompanied by a clock with +ve transitions mid-bit.
- Every 5 msec the data stream transmits 2000 bytes
- Each byte will have one start bit, eight data bits and one stop bit (no parity).

Comment: so you want a PCI<->SSP bridge with windows drivers?  What kind of SSP are you after? SPI? SSI? Microwire?

Comment: If you are referring to the Microsoft thing, it is generally written '.NET' rather than 'dotNET'

Comment: The data is RS422/485, uni-directional, externally clocked and fairly fast!

Comment: RS422/485 do not have a clock, they're asynchronous. So... what?

Comment: RS422 doesn't have to be driven by a uart. It defines only the physical layer. I assume the interface has two RS422 channels operating in parallel. One for the clock and one for the data. (Although I don't know why you would then have start & stop bits...)

Comment: The interface specification was developed to read the data stream into an embedded 68000 - if there is a UART product out there capable of 10Mbps with a suitable interface then that would be perfect!

Answer (score 1):

[SeaLevel Systems](http://www.sealevel.com/store/serial/synchronous-serial/pci/5104s-pci-rs-232-rs-422-rs-485-rs-530-rs-530a-v-35-synchronous-serial-interface-uses-z16c32.html) makes a synchronous board that does 10 Mbit. Have not used their products but they have been in business for at least a few years. Even if they don't have a native .NET interface, keep in mind that you can call 'unsafe' code from .NET environments.

[General Standards](http://www.generalstandards.com/view-products.php?product=PCI-SIO8BXS) also makes a board. They are pricey.

Another thing to consider is using a PMC card on a PCI carrier. Note that this is at least a $1500 solution.

Comment: I prefer to call it 'native' code. :-) Unsafe makes people scared

Comment: I assume that was the intention though :)